# How can I get the number of significant digits of the data stored in a NetCDF file?

Tags: netcdf

I need to know the precision of the data stored in a NetCDF file.

I think that it is possible to know this precision because, when I dump a NetCDF file using ncdump, the number of significant digits displayed depends on the particular NetCDF file that I am using.

So, for one file I get:

> `Ts = -0.2121478, -0.08816089, -0.4285178, -0.3446428, -0.4800949,
>       -0.4332879, -0.2057121, -0.06589077, -0.001647412, 0.007711744,`

And for another one:

> `Ts = -2.01, -3.6, -1, -0.53, -1.07, -0.7, -0.56, -1.3, -0.93, -1.41, -0.83,
>       -0.8, -2.13, -2.91, -1.13, -1.2, -2.23, -1.77, -2.93, -0.7, -2.14, -1.36,`

I also have to say that there is no information about precision in any attribute, neither global nor local to the variable. You can see this in the dump of the header of the NetCDF file:

```
netcdf pdo {
dimensions:
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (809 currently)
variables:
    double time(time) ;
            time:units = "months since 1900-01-01" ;
            time:calendar = "gregorian" ;
            time:axis = "T" ;
    double Ts(time) ;
            Ts:missing_value = NaN ;
            Ts:name = "Ts" ;

// global attributes:
            :Conventions = "CF-1.0" ;
}
```

Does anybody know how can I get the number of significant digits of the data stored in a NetCDF file?.

Comment: I have found [this](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/mailing_lists/archives/netcdfgroup/2016/msg00189.html) thread in the Unidata forum. It seems that precision should be stored in some attribute, but it is not. And, however, ncdump can display the correct precision, so, I think that it gets it in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky question: what `ncdump` (and many other pretty number generators) does is simply strip the trailing zeros from the fractional part, but does that say anything about the real (observed/calculated/..) precision of the values? Something measured with three decimals accuracy might be `1.100`, yet `ncdump` will still print it as `1.1`. If you want to know the true (physical?) significance, it would indeed have to be included as an attribute, or documented elsewhere.

For a large set of numbers, counting the maximum number of significant digits in the fractional part of the numbers could be a first indication of the precision. If that is what you are looking for, something like this might work in Python:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.01, 2.0])
b = np.array([1.10, 1])
c = np.array([10., 200.0001])
d = np.array([1, 2])

def count_max_significant_fraction(array):
    # Return zero for any integer type array:
    if issubclass(array.dtype.type, np.integer):
        return 0
    decimals = [s.rstrip('0').split('.')[1] for s in array.astype('str')]
    return len(max(decimals, key=len))

print( count_max_significant_fraction(a) )   # prints "2"
print( count_max_significant_fraction(b) )   # prints "1"
print( count_max_significant_fraction(c) )   # prints "4"
print( count_max_significant_fraction(d) )   # prints "0"
```

Comment: Thank you @Bart, but there is still one caveat. When a number like 1.8 was stored and afterwards is read as 1.7999999999992 for example. Could you provide additional code for this situation?.

Comment: 1.8 (and many other values, see e.g. http://floating-point-gui.de/) can only be approximated in computers. Storing 1.8 in a single precision float gives me a number very similar to yours, so perhaps they used single precision floats before storing it in double precision in the NetCDF file. But this is again difficult if you don't know the original precision of the data; 1.7999999999992 could be a precise observed/calculated number, or it could be the nearest floating point approximation of 1.8

Comment: Ok. So, I will take care of the precision of the original data. I will find out the precision of the original data, and then, I will add an attribute in the NetCDF file (by creating a new NetCDF file) that will hold the number of significant digits. For the cases in which I cannot find out the original precision, I will use your code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you adopt the convention NCO uses and name the precision attribute "number_of_significant_digits" and/or "least_significant_digit". Terms are defined in the lengthy precision discussion that starts [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ppc).